# How to filter nested fields in a JSONField using Django ORM with Djongo?

Tags: python, django, django-models, djongo

I am working on a Django project where I am using Djongo as an ORM for MongoDB. I have a model named **ProcessIDs** which contains a **JSONField** named **data**. Within this **JSONField**, there are nested fields, and I am trying to filter the model entities based on a nested field value. Specifically, I am looking to filter based on the value of **data->redirect_ids->status**.

I attempted to use the following query to filter the model entities:

```
active_processes = ProcessIDs.objects.filter(data__redirect_ids__status__exact='active')
```

I was expecting this query to return all **ProcessIDs** objects where the **status** field under **redirect_ids** nested within the **data** field is set to '**active**'. However, executing this query resulted in a **FieldError** with the following message:

```
FieldError: Unsupported lookup ‘redirect_ids’ for JSONField or join on the field not permitted.
```

I am looking for a way to achieve the desired filtering using Django ORM with Djongo. Is there a specific syntax or method to filter based on nested field values within a **JSONField** in this setup?

```py
from djongo import models as mongo_models

class ProcessIDs(mongo_models.Model):
    data = mongo_models.JSONField(max_length=1000, default=dict())
    # ... other fields ...

# Example object creation
process = ProcessIDs.objects.create(
    data={'redirect_ids': {'ids': ['1234567', '7654321'], 'status': 'active'}, "category_type": "custom"}
)

# Attempted query
active_processes = ProcessIDs.objects.filter(data__redirect_ids__status__exact='active')
```

Comment: Usually if data is structured, it makes not much sense to store that as a JSON blob in a *relational* database, because it makes querying less expressive and less efficient as well.